# Speed controlling of AC motor with dimmer

Tags: dimmer, ac-motor

I have a fan which has asynchronous motor. It's features are that 230V AC, 50 Hz, 50W. I want to control it's speed using AC dimmer. I can control the brightness of light bulb with my dimmer circuit. It works totally fine.

I tried the same thing with that fan. However, the problem is that I can't run that fan in every delay time. It's understandable that fan does not work when I implement a long delay. Before every delay, I start fan with full speed for 10 seconds.

I can run the fan between 3.5-7 ms. I just don't understand why it does not work when I implement small delays like 1-1.5 ms.

Imagine I implement 1 ms delay. I run it with full speed for 10 seconds. After 10 seconds, it does not work properly. It makes noise and coil winding gets pretty hot.

Why am I facing this problem? Also how can I solve that problem ?

Comment: What kind of dimmer are you using? Your question suggests you're using a PWM-based dimmer, which would be ideal on something like a DC motor, however I think it will introduce additional problems here. A potentiometer-style dimmer might solve your problem?

Comment: @MrMeowMeow I use potentiometer-style dimmer.

Comment: Then what are your comments about delay?

Comment: @MrMeowMeow It is about how much mains I let go through.

Comment: So you're running the motor on full voltage initially for 10ms, then turning down the voltage after that?

Comment: @MrMeowMeow Yeah I run the motor full voltage for 10ms, after that I implement the delay which means that delay will decide how much of mains will go through.

Comment: Is the fan motor a universal style motor with brushes or an induction motor. Induction motors don’t like being phase controlled.

Comment: @Kartman Production description says that it is shaded-pole motor. So I guess it is induction motor.

Comment: Indeed it is. You can buy speed controllers specifically for small fans which will probably be suitable.

Comment: @Kartman I dont have much knowledge about motors. Can you please explain why I can't control it with dimmer?

Comment: An induction motor’s speed is tied to the mains frequency. If you control the voltage with a dimmer  then the motor wastes energy as heat as the motor is not rotating at the required speed. This is a simplified description. If you use a dimmer with a power drill or vacuum cleaner motor that have brushes, then you can control the speed from near 0 to flat oot.

Answer (score 1):

Mains light dimmers intended for incandescent bulbs use phase control. The dimmer output is not turned on until later in each mains cycle, with the turn-on point set by the adjustment potentiometer. This delivers a chopped mains waveform to the bulb at the same mains frequency.

An induction motor's rotational speed and torque is set by the frequency and amplitude of the voltage across its two windings. The second winding uses a capacitor to add a phase shift to the applied voltage frequency. The motor speed cannot be adjusted by phase control. If you try, then it will run badly as the phase chopping is increased then stop when phase chopping reaches a small fairly amount.

Instead, induction motor speed would be controlled using an inverter to adjust the applied voltage frequency and amplitude.

Comment: You forgot to mention about rotor sliding in asynchronous motor. Motor speed is depends on load too. It can be controlled by changing effective voltage. But start current is 4-7 times higher then working current and OP probably tried to start motor with too low voltage and not enough current to start.